# trajectory error in simulation / controller parameters

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a student at University of Stuttgart and work at IPA Fraunhofer with the Care-O-bot.
We have here some problems with the planned trajectory in simulation. The actual executed trajectory of the robot arm in rviz differs from the planned one (display_path (motion_planning_msgs/DisplayTrajectory)). We guess that it comes from the dynamic model and the chosen controller parameters in the arm_controller_cob3-1.yaml file (cob_simulation/cob_controller_configuration_gazebo/ros/controller).
So we're looking for ideas, hints and rules how to choose these parameters or explanations where the trajectory error could come from.

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9052/trajectory-error-in-simulation-/-controller-parameters/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path you are seeing is indeed the path that comes from the planner.  But there's an extra step that move_arm goes through of filtering the trajectory using a spline_shortcutting method that tries to find ways to make the path shorter while also assigning reasonable velocities when it can.  This can change the trajectory quite a bit.  If you want to see the path that move_arm will actually be sending to be executed you'll need to change the code a bit.  Overlay arm_navigation.  In whatever version of the code you are running find the line:

visualizePlan(current_trajectory_);  //move_arm_simple_action.cpp:1361 in unstable.

Comment this line out, and then copy it an add it after the line:

current_trajectory_ = filtered_trajectory; //move_arm_simple_action.cpp:1422 in unstable
visualizePlan(current_trajectory_); // copied from 1361

The trajectory you see in rviz will now be the actual one getting passed to the controller.  I expect it will look much more like the executed trajectory.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3